# "Attempting to access a socket in a forbidden way" when trying to connect to mySql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, uwp

I get an "Attempting to access a socket in a forbidden way error" when I'm trying to connect to the MySQL database eventhought I have all the rights with said database

- I've tried to use ODBC connector butit doesn't seem to be compatible with UWP app
- I've tried to use Net Connector with MySQL.Data.RT.dll and MySQL.Data
- I've tried to change my connection string with driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver} or by adding option=3

```
string connChaine = "server=10.12.x.x;user=user;database=database;port=3306;password=*****;";
            MySqlConnection connexion = new MySqlConnection(connChaine);
            try
            {
                await MessageBox("Connexion à MySql ...");
                connexion.Open();

                //Opérations 
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM glpi_computers";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connexion);
                MySqlDataReader lecteur = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (lecteur.Read())
                {
                    await MessageBox(lecteur[0] + "--" + lecteur[1]);
                }
                lecteur.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await MessageBox(ex.ToString());
            }
            connexion.Close();
```

Comment: Did you add right permission .. 10.0.0.0 is private network ...

Comment: I can connect with the ODBC driver, so I'm not sure that this is a matter of permission

Comment: This is almost certainly a firewall/infrastructure issue, not a code issue. Can you `telnet` to that server on port 3306?

Comment: this is the result  : "[
 5.5.60-0ubuntu0.14.04.1ü#$-R7[DÇ}q@+R<wabFxLmysql_native_password

Perte de la connexion à l’hôte" (translation : connection to the host lost)

Comment: Please post the full exception details: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ Also, try using MySqlConnector; it has better netstandard support: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: @LaïlaB Have you added Private Network capbility in your package.manifest? Where is your server located? Are you testing this on the same machine?

Comment: I tried with a Windows form and it work perfectly , it is NOT an infrastructure issue

Comment: @LaïlaB Winform is different here. It does not require capbility and it is using different dll. Can you check the capbility I mentioned and shows the result to us? Please understand the error info is almost saying that your connection is stopped by permission, we need to find out what permission is the key that you missed first.